# Why does '00a0' show on my page

Tags: html, unicode

Here is an image of my website. It should not have '00A0'.

[image: Picture of my page]

[Link to website with bad character](http://imrankhaliq.com/thecoder101/codingPage.php?tutId=14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove ":before" and ":after" style from "code"[image]

Comment: codingPage.php line 24, <style>.... look for the :before stuff.  ... content: 00a0

Comment: I can't delete ::before in inspect element and it doesn't show up in my html code.

Comment: If you can't delete, you can add the following code "code:after, code:before { display: none; }"